# How do i format a string in an email so that in outlook it will look in Tabular format?

Tags: java

I wanted to generate an email from java.By formatting the message body to look like a tabular format with proper alignment.Can any one please help me how to format a  message body into tabular format?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Are you just looking to put an HTML table into an HTML-formatted email?  It doesn't sound like Java itself is even really relevant here.

Comment: are you sending email in text/plain or text/html format? If it is text/plain, then the appearance depends on the font family configured by the client and so it may not appear in a strict tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set your Message to accept html

here is a working example

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
.......
msg.setSubject(subject);
.......
MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp1.setContent(html, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
msg.setContent(mp);
```

From there on it is up to you how you want to format the appearance of the message (**html** variable in the example above)